# Are mutliple statements without transaction possible using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to update 2 tables at the same time where the inserted index of the first should be inserted into the 2nd table.
The sql looks like this:

```
DECLARE @nrTable table (TXT_nr int)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT txt FROM tbl1 WHERE txt = (?))
INSERT INTO tbl1 (txt, new) OUTPUT INSERTED.nr INTO @nrTable VALUES((?), 1)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT txt FROM tbl1 WHERE txt =(?)) 
INSERT INTO tbl2 (TXT_nr, field1, field2)
VALUES((SELECT TXT_nr FROM @nrTable), (?), (?))
WHERE field3 = (?) AND field4 = (?)
```

I am trying to accomplish this using

```
this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batch);
```

simply concatenating the lines in java using basic strings. This seems to only execute the first statement, though.
Now the reason I don´t want to do this transactionally is that I would have to do it using a loop just inserting one batch-object at a time, because of the ouput-clause. This would result in loads of calls to the sql-server.

Is there any known way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use batchupdate in this way. Please refer to this document http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html

And to achieve your goal, if you are using a sequence in sql, then you need to get the new value in java and store it in your query. Like this :

```
long id = jdbcTemplace.queryForObject("select sequence_name.nextval from dual",Long.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
As I said I don´t want to store the value in Java, if possible, because it would be a bunch of statements sent to the server instead of just one batch. I am well aware of the transactional stuff your link is all about. Doens´t answer my question at all, though.